# Protractor browser.get() throwing exception in IE11

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, internet-explorer-11, end-to-end

I'm trying to run a simple protractor test in IE11 on Win 8.1.

My test:

```
it("should navigate to from the homepage to the add contact page", function () {
    browser.get("http://localhost:4000/");
    // ... it already crashes here
});
```

My config:

```
exports.config = {
// run in multiple browsers
multiCapabilities:[    
    {
       'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    }
],

specs: ['./**/*js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},

onPrepare: function () {
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
    );
}
};
```

The error:

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://169.254.80.80:31289/wd/hub
[31mF[0m

Failures:

  1) add new contact page should navigate to from the homepage to the add contact page
   Message:
     [31mUnknownError: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'Florian-Lenovo', ip: '169.254.80.80', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:22540/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 2b2e9619-3eb8-493f-bc9d-5354a91f7f8b[0m
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'Florian-Lenovo', ip: '169.254.80.80', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:22540/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 2b2e9619-3eb8-493f-bc9d-5354a91f7f8b
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)
    at C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:362:20
    at C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:420:7)
    at [object Object].fulfill (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:535:5)
    at C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1520:10
==== async task ====
Protractor.get(http://localhost:4000/) - reset url
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:345:15)
    at [object Object].Protractor.executeScript_ (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:223:22)
    at [object Object].Protractor.get (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:440:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\OneDrive\Projects\Gyst\Gyst.Web\Scripts\tests\e2e\contacts\addNewContactSpecs.ts:10:17)
    at C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1518:8)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at onComplete (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
    at [object Object].jasmine.WaitsForBlock.execute (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2704:5)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2718:12)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\OneDrive\Projects\Gyst\Gyst.Web\Scripts\tests\e2e\contacts\addNewContactSpecs.ts:9:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\OneDrive\Projects\Gyst\Gyst.Web\Scripts\tests\e2e\contacts\addNewContactSpecs.ts:1:34)

Finished in 1.015 seconds
[31m1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure
[0m
Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] internet explorer #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

I'm still pretty new to protractor and I don't have a clue what to do with this.
My tests run fine in Chrome and Firefox.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is it an angular app you are testing against? What if you add `allScriptsTimeout: 300000,` to the protractor configuration? What if you open up `browser.get("https://angularjs.org/");` - same error? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to run the test against chrome to rule out it is an IE driver problem?

Answer (score 2):

try this one, for me it helped with a similar error saying `A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.`

protractor-conf.js

```
{"browserName": "internet explorer",
    "ie.forceCreateProcessApi": true,
    "ie.browserCommandLineSwitches": "-private",
    "ie.ensureCleanSession": "true",
    "seleniumAddress": 'http://10.0.1.XXX:4444/wd/hub'
}
```

Ensure that `TabProcGrowth" = dword: 00000000` in Path  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` is set.

Answer (score 1):

IEExplorerDriver is expected to implement asynchronous script executions except that there are a couple of known issues, that the driver can be slow and often times out waiting for page load:

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/browser-setup

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1052

In your case as per the logs you provided, the lines somehow indicates a timeout has happen.

It's still an open issue for the Protactor team and hopefully, they will come up with a solution soon.

Another thing to possibly consider is that, Protactor uses Promises in order to execute scripts asynchronously, which in terms of browser support is currently still in Preview release in IE11

https://status.modern.ie/promiseses6

Answer (score 0):

For none angular sites instead of driver.get use below code .

browser.driver.get("https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/radioButton");

Also go Internet options in IE>IE options  and enable protected mode for all the zones

I managed to solve this with below capabilities in my config,js

```
 onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;// for non-angular set true. default value is false 
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);   // for non-angular set false. default value is true  
      browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);

       }, 
 capabilities: {
     browserName: 'internet explorer',
     platform: 'ANY',
     version: '11'
    },
```